# How to post a collected value to a new page

Tags: php

I am still learning PHP and am now completely stuck - any help would be so much appreciated! Scenario: HTML form for user to complete, among other things, they have to select with a radio button how many tickets they want to buy. My PHP file compiles all the values into an email and sends it off - that part works perfectly - and then redirects the browser to my "thank you for completing the form" page. I would now like to display a value collected in the form on this thank you page: the amount of tickets the user selected with the radio button. How do i call the 'tickets' value to the thank you page?
Thank you ever so much!

Here is the HTML form:
http://menusolutions.co.za/maidens2014_booking_form.html

Here is my "sendmail3.php" file that sends my mail:

```
$webmaster_email = "carin@menusolutions.co.za";

$feedback_page = "maidens2014.html";
$error_page = "maidens_error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "maidens_thank_you.php";

$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$telephone = $_POST['telephone'] ;
$cell = $_POST['cell'] ;
$email_address = $_POST['email_address'] ;
$address = $_POST['address'] ;
$tickets = $_POST['tickets'] ;


$mail_body = "Name: $name \n Telephone: $telephone \n Cell: $cell \n Email: email_address \n Address: $address \n Tickets: $tickets";
mail( "$webmaster_email", "Maidens Bowled Over 2014",
  $mail_body, "From: $email_address" );
header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}

?>
```

And here is my thank you page, upon which I need to display the 'tickets' value so that people can be reminded how many tickets they bought and the amount they need to pay:
http://menusolutions.co.za/maidens_thank_you.php

Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Pass the ticker number as querystring or in case of safely put in the Session

Comment: set the values in a session and then display it in the thank you page and detroy it. else you can also send those details through the thank you page url which you can get using $_GET in the thank you page

Answer (score 2):

You can send ticket value inside URL or using session.

```
header( "Location:". $thankyou_page.'?ticket='.$tickets );
```

and on thanks you page add below code,

```
$tickets = $_GET['tickets'];
echo $tickets . ' tickets.';
```

Comment: Hi Dipesh, thank you for your answer. I replaced the last line in my "sendmail3.php" with your first line of code, and the added your two lines in on the thank you page - however what happens now is that what is displayed is: Amount due: tickets. (instead of the amount of tickets)
Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Although this is the basic idea, keep in mind that echoing $_GET values without any escaping can be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) to accomplish that.

An other option is redirecting and using a GET value.
On your sendmail.php page you can use header to redirect the user :

```
header('location: thanks_page.php?ticketValue='.$ticketValue);
```

Be careful that : *header() must be called before any actual output is sent.* (see [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).)

And then get it back in your thanks_page in `$_GET['ticketValue']` and do not forget to espace the value with `htmlspecialchars` or an equivalent for security !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to redirect to the "thank you"-page and add the ticket value as a get-parameter

**Link**

```
maidens_thank_you.php?tickets=$tickets
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a GET parameter for this. For example,

```
header('Location: ' . $thankyou_page . '?tickets=' . $tickets);
```

And then in your *thank you* page (which I assume is a PHP script), you could retrieve that value using.

```
$tickets = $_GET['tickets'];
echo 'Thank you! You bought ' . $tickets . ' tickets.';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a session or pass the values in the url by  making your $thankyou page something like

```
$thankyoupage + "?numberoftickets=" + $numberoftickets;
header('Location:' + $thankyoupage);
```

and get the value back by

```
 $_GET['numberoftickets']
```

in your actual thankyoupage.
only use the session method if you need the var in other pages than the thankyoupage too. sessions make this value available in your hole application.
more information about sessions can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Answer (score 0):

Never use a varible in double quotes ("") it's will be string so use direct. you need to more learn php
for mail tuts :- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
mail( $webmaster_email, "Maidens Bowled Over 2014",
      $mail_body, $email_address );
    header( "Location:". $thankyou_page );
```